# How to write an oracle database trigger query ensuring that a condition of more than 5 days must be met

Tags: oracle, triggers

Good Day all

Please i have an oracle trigger query that i can't figure out how to go about it.

They trigger is like this:

> Write a trigger query ensuring that holiday of less than seven days duration cannot be allowed

Thanks for your response

Comment: If you expect a complete answer you'll need to post a complete question, which in this case means posting a table structure and some sample data which demonstrates passing and failing conditions.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on a table, i.e. the way you store that info. If it is just a single-row data, e.g.

```
ID   Name     Type     Duration (days)
---  -------  -------  ---------------
100  Charlyo  Holiday  8
```

then you'd

```
create or replace trigger trg_biu_test
  before insert or update on table_name
  for each row
begin
  if :new.type = 'Holiday' and :new.duration < 7 then
     raise_application_error (-20000, 'Holiday can not be shorter than 7 days');
  end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: I doubt that this is the underlying table structure, but if it is this a situation in which a CHECK constraint would be appropriate and not a trigger.

Comment: To me, @APC, it looks like someone's (homework?) assignment, not real life problem. But, I might be wrong.

Comment: Almost certainly it is homework. Unfortunately teachers are very bad at deigning exercises with good use cases for triggers (before there are so few such cases). All the more reason for us to point out that this is a bad use for a trigger :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is helpful